# Ejecutar código javascript cuando un elemento llega la parte superior de la ventana (top)

Tags: javascript

tengo el sigueinte codigo:

```
const elem = document.querySelector('#cambio');
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= elem.getBoundingClientRect().top || document.documentElement.scrollTop > elem.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
  console.log("hacer algo");
  }
}
```

Esta function muestra el console.log cuando el scroll llega a tocar el elemento. Lo que quisiera es que el script se ejecute cuando el elemento llegue al top de la ventana.

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh la solucion era esta:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('#cambio');
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop >= elem.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
  console.log("hacer algo");
  }
}
```